# How to get and invoke method with array parameters with Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I need to get and invoke the two following methods with reflection:

```
buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(Table table, String keyName, String[] columnNames)
buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(Table table, String keyName, String[] columnNames, String[] orderings, boolean unique)
```

I have tried the following, but without any luck:

```
Method buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames1 = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames",
Table.class, String.class, String[].class);
Method buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames2 = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames",
Table.class, JPAIndexHolder.class, UniqueConstraintHolder.class, String[].class, String[].class, Boolean.class);
```

This just resulted in NoSuchMethodException. I suspect that it has to something to do with the array parameters.

How to I get and invoke these two methods correctly using reflection?

Comment: None of the declared methods you're included in your method list has these parameters: `JPAIndexHolder.class, UniqueConstraintHolder.class`. In that, the `NoSuchMethodException` is founded.

Comment: Are these methods public or can you access them from the location where you want to invoke? Second one, are they static?

Answer (score 0):

How to use reflection:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("method name", parameterTypes);
method.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, params);
```

Where:

- "class name" is the name of the class
- objectToInvokeOn is of type Object and is the object you want to invoke the method on
- "method name" is the name of the method you want to call
- parameterTypes is of type Class [] and decalres the parameters the method  - params is of type Object [] and declares the parameters to be passed to the method

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to @Dsenese1's answer.
You have to handle errors with try catch block in case of error throwing.
Otherwise you cannot build it

```
try{
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
    Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("method name", parameterTypes);
    method.invoke(objectToInvokeOn, params);
}catch(Exception e){
    //Handle error
}
```